# why would https://secure-a.vimeocdn.com/js/froogaloop2.min.js delay my site load time?

Tags: performance, vimeo, load-time, froogaloop

It seems just recently my site's load-time is being delayed for about 30seconds due to Vimeo's https://secure-a.vimeocdn.com/js/froogaloop2.min.js.

What i don't understand is that if i follow the link directly it loads up instantly so i am not sure why it would it cause load time delays on my site?

i already checked with my host and they see no problem on their end.

anyone have some insight?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who comes across this as well, for some reason that link just doesn't seem to work anymore, although I couldn't really find any news as to why, the newer link is this one:

https://secure-f.vimeocdn.com/js/froogaloop2.min.js

That works as of today